# Which issue of Marvel comic books first featured Peter Parker taking a "Selfie"?

Tags: marvel, meme, the-amazing-spider-man

Did Peter take the pictures from the very first issue, or was the ploy introduced as the series unfolded?

Which issue of *the Amazing Spider-Man* series did News Photographer, or the soon to be News Photographer Peter Parker start taking web mounted camera *Selfie* crime fighting pictures with him dressed as Spider-Man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**Amazing Spider-man #2, Duel To The Death With The Vulture, Lee/Ditko - May 1963**

The Vulture, in his 1st appearance, begins a crime spree, which culminates with the theft of a diamond shipment. Spider-Man defeats the Vulture disabling his wings with a device he thought up from their earlier encounter in that issue. Peter Parker begins selling photos to the Daily Bugle.

> The Vulture decides to next rob the Park Avenue Jewelry Exchange when Spider-Man sees him. He starts taking pictures but is spotted by the Vulture. They fight briefly before the Vulture flies away. Peter takes his pictures to Jameson who is impressed by the photos. The Vulture tries to trick everyone by attempting to rob the Jewelry Exchange from below rather than above (as people would expect). Spider-Man's spider-sense goes off and he's able to capture the Vulture. Having more photos of the Vulture and the fight with Spider-Man, Peter is able to sell them and earn more money for Aunt May and himself.